# How to set many unique two-way binding ng-model inside nested ng-repeats (table) in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Link to [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2mhrpqEdlxgPZWgFqlxV?p=preview).

I want to be able to uniquely change the model of each `values`, but currently when I type inside the any form field, all of them change.

Basically, I have a table created using two ng-repeats for rows and columns.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in solved track by $index" ng-init= "rowIndex = $index">
      <td ng-repeat ="cell in row track by $index">
        <form>
           <input ng-model="solved[rowIndex][$index].value" type="number"/>
        </form>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When the angular is init, I run a clearBoard() function which sets the default data structure of `solved` to this:

```
$scope.clearBoard = function() {
    var blank = { value: null }
    $scope.solved = [
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank],
    [blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank]]
};
```

I initially started with `ng-model="cell.value"` but changed to the current solution when I thought that the `rowIndex` and `$index` would be able to identify the correct cell.

This part is just for clarity sake for you. It's not in my production.

```
{{$index}}
{{rowIndex}}
```

*Update:* I also came up with a way to initialize the empty board using underscoreJS.

```
$scope.clearBoard = function() {
    var solved = [];
    var empty = { value: null };

    _(9).times(function() {
        var row = [];
        _(9).times(function() {
            row.push(_.clone(empty))
        });
        solved.push(row)
    });

    $scope.solved = solved;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the variable `blank` in each array slot, it is actually referencing the same object, which is why they all change together.  Your tracking by `$index` is working!  Try this to load your array with separate objects instead:

```
$scope.solved = [
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }],
    [{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null },{ value: null }]]
```

Link to working Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/dfnNcFFsh53Hwb4gdf9r?p=preview

UPDATE:  Here's a DRYer way to do it:

```
// init the array
$scope.solved = [];

// define number of rows and cols
var cols = 9; 
var rows = 9;

// generate rows
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

    // init an array for each row
    $scope.solved[i] = [];

    // generate columns
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        $scope.solved[i].push({ value: null });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've literally spent 6+ hours on this stupid bug.

Comment: do you know any way so I can initialize that blank state in a more DRY way?

Comment: See update.  You could also take `cols` and `rows` as params to a function to create any sized array if you so desired. :)

Comment: thanks dude. I also came up with a method using underscore JS. Check it out in the original post if you're interested! The site is live too: kill-all-sudoku.herokuapp.com